# Get the declaration source from a variable usage site

Tags: c#, vb.net, roslyn

An Example

```
Console.WriteLine( arg )
```

I am trying to get the corresponding symbol (not an interface) where `arg` was declared / defined. So I can for example if we say the following code is the definition site.

```
Dim x = "Hello World"
```

So that I can get the span / location of the assigned value `Hello World`
Note that not after the text as I can get that value of the variable `arg` at the usage site.
The debugger Local / Watch window show the type `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Symbols.LocalSymbol.VariableLocalSymbol`

unfortunately this is `internal`

If some one knows, could you please provide an example.

Comment: By definition site do you just mean, for example, where go to definition would take you?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Don't is the best way (but it works for what I need it for.)

```vb
Dim ThisIdentifier = CType(TheFormatString.Expression, IdentifierNameSyntax)
If ThisIdentifier Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim ConstValue = semanticModel.GetConstantValue(ThisIdentifier, cancellationToken)
If ConstValue.HasValue = False Then Exit Sub

Dim FoundSymbol = semanticModel.LookupSymbols(TheFormatString.Expression.Span.Start, name:=ThisIdentifier.Identifier.Text)(0)
Dim VariableDeclarationSite = TryCast(FoundSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences(0).GetSyntax.Parent, VariableDeclaratorSyntax)
If VariableDeclarationSite Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim TheValueOfTheVariable = VariableDeclarationSite.Initializer.Value
```